# Run Spring Boot application on multiple server address

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, networking

Just curious about this!!
I have a spring boot application running on 10.0.0.1(9000 port) and same instance has a subnet for 10.0.0.2 
The application is running on pid P1, How can I bind my Spring boot application to both the server address which must point to same process P1 and on same port 9000

```
10.0.0.1:9000/api
10.0.0.2:9000/api
```

The application must be accessible on both the server address without using create the new instance or new port,

I have tried using reverse proxy and proxy but still no luck,
Is possible to do ?

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/873953 Looking something similar to this in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

First way: find it on `0.0.0.0` which will then be available on all ip addresses.

Second way: Use a reverse proxy like `nginx` which listens on 10.0.0.2:9000 and forwards to your spring. (you mentioned it does not work. could you please give more details?)

Third way: let your spring listen on another port, say 8888. then use nginx to listen on both 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 and forward. Actually in *production* environment this is also very common (placing a reverse proxy before actual workload).

Comment: Running it on `0.0.0.0` will make it accessible for the system ip right ?

Comment: in third way I have to create a different instance that means different process, I am trying to do the bind in same process ID

Comment: using proxy in nginx is leading to request forwarding, adds a bit of latency, It works fine but looking for something without nginx

Comment: @BimalGangawal yes 0.0.0.0 is for all ips. actually request forwarding latency is very small compared with spring boot... if you really need high performance, you may have to use a C++/Rust framework, or Netty for Java, etc, but *not* spring... In other words, if you use Spring, the extra latency (and extra CPU and memory) is not a problem compared with the speed and cpu and memory of Spring itself

Comment: True agreed that there will be extra latency by using spring, nginx will further add to that. what i am looking here is creating two sockets binding to different ip and same port running on same processID

Comment: @BimalGangawal I wonder why you want to do so? maybe this is a A-B problem

Comment: I am exploring a possibility out of curiousness, i feel it to be a good use case to achieve to over come network congestion or queue surges without adding additional CPU

Comment: For security reasons is not recomended bind 0.0.0.0, by example, binding to internal and private vpn or on a virtual network. For better practice use the two specific interfaces.